# JSFiddle won't show result first on medium embed

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, medium-editor

I am trying to embed a JSFiddle element in a medium post with the result showing first like this: https://blog.mapbox.com/3d-features-in-mapbox-gl-js-e94734f12110

When I post the URL (with the correct embed url fromat  http://{url_of_the_fiddle}/embedded/[{tabs}/[{style}]]/). It shows this the fiddle with all tabs:
[fiddle all tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq5FR.png)

How can I show just the results in medium?

Comment: Can you show the actual url you tried? (Or an other example fiddle with the same result if you don't want to show the actual one)

Comment: the blog link you posted already don't show a valid jsFiddle

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious, but you can add a "show" flag in the url to only post the result tab. The result link they will give you will look something like this `http://{url_of_the_fiddle}/show/embedded/`

Real example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dugbvezs/show/embedded/

Comment: Ah, it does work when I remove my user name from the fiddle link.

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore. Neither with username nor without it